# find in database table variable

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm quit new in all this so can you help me?

I'm running wordpress site and I've got in my MySql database table named *price_table* and it has two columns: *name*, *price*

I need variable to be found in the table column *name* and if it exists there, return *price* values form that row.

Something like this:

```
$value = "com";
$sql = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->price_table WHERE name = '$value'");

echo $sql->price;
```

Please help me how to do it right?

Thanks.

Comment: use get_row instead of get_var ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`get_row`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/) or [`get_results`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for getting records from database:

**With `get_row`:**

```
$sql = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->price_table WHERE name = '$value'");

if($wpdb->num_rows > 0){
   echo $sql->price;
}
```

**With `get_results`:**

```
$sql = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->price_table WHERE name = '$value'");
if($wpdb->num_rows > 0){
  foreach ($sql as $result) {
    echo $result->price;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked perefect except 1 issue. I had to remove $wpdb-> from FROM $wpdb->price_table.

Comment: @SergiKhizanishvili: glad to help u friend

Answer (score 0):

you can use [get_row](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_row/) for getting records from database:

Here is the get_row code

```
$sql = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->price_table WHERE name = '$value'");
if($wpdb->num_rows > 0){
     echo $sql->price;
}
```